# How does one create an object from an array of data items?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, foreach, reduce

I'm struggling to create an object from an array in JS.
I keep getting an error when pushing into the plots object.

```
makeArrayFilteredPlots = () => {
  let plots = {};
  this.props.filteredPlots.forEach((plot) => {
    const status = plot.entity.status.slug;
    plots[status].push(plot);
  });
  console.log(plots);
};
```

Comment: Please define [it's not working](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/). What have you tried to solve the problem? For instance, did you try logging things like `console.log(plot)`? What does it output?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You declared plots as const, do it var.

Comment: The target format is not even valid JS syntax. One can not clearly see whether the OP wants to generate array items, where each item is an object with a single key (or something else). From the generating code it looks like the OP wants to generate an object where each entry (key value pair) is an array. But then we are not talking about an multi dimensional array.

Comment: `plots[status]` makes no sense (if `status` is a string); `plots` is an array, it's a list of things. It has no keys, so `plots[status]` is undefined. You are pushing data into an undefined object. Your console must be telling you this.

Comment: Do you need the outer array to be ordered? It looks like it would be more suitable as an object. e.g. `{ 'te-koop': [...], 'in-optie': [...], 'verkocht': [...] }`

Comment: I'm getting this error message: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push'). I've already done some debugging and console logged every party in the function, they're all logging correctly. Status is a string, plots are objects with several fields.

Comment: @JoséCarlosPHP That is not necessary. They are not reassigning anywhere. You can keys to an object declared with `const`

Comment: The desired result seems to be based on PHP syntax. OP: In Javascript, and associative array is written as an "object", meaning it uses `{ key: 'value' }` syntax, while iterative arrays use `[ 'value1', 'value2' ]` syntax.

Comment: Correct, the data structure you are trying to make does not exist in JS. Arrays don't have names keys. Make an object instead

Comment: Change: `const plots = {}` and then below the `status` declaration line: `plots[status] = plots[status] || []; plots[status].push(plot)`. You will get an object with status as key and array of grouped objects as the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In JS, an array has no named keys, it's only a list of things. If you want named keys, use an object `{}`
2. `plots[status]` is never initialized. When you try to `.push()` stuff in something undefined, the script crashes. Initialize it to an empty array before starting to push things in it.

```js
makeArrayFilteredPlots = () => {
  let plots = {};
  this.props.filteredPlots.forEach((plot) => {
    const status = plot.entity.status.slug;
    plots[status] = plots[status] || []; // Initialize an empty array
    plots[status].push(plot);
  });
  console.log(plots);
};
```

Comment: I removed the second point regarding mutation. `const plots = {}; plots.key = "value"` or `const array= []; array.push("value")` are valid code. Only reassignment is not allowed `plots = { "key": "another value" }`

Answer (score 0):

From the above comment ...

> *"The target format is not even valid JS syntax. One can not clearly see whether the OP wants to generate array items, where each item is an object with a single key (or something else). From the generating code it looks like the OP wants to create/aggregate an object where each entry (key value pair) is an array. But then we are not talking about a multi dimensional array."*

Sophisticated guess ... a [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) based task should solve the OP's problem of generating a configuration like **object of** `plot` specific **arrays** ...

```
const plotsConfig = this
  .props
  .filteredPlots
  .reduce((result, plot) => {

    const plotKey = plot.entity.status.slug;
    const plotList = result[plotKey] ??= [];

    plotList.push(plot);
    
    return result;

  }, {});
```